# Should I Use the Default SQL Server 2012 Accounts or Make Specific Ones?

Tags: sql-server, virtualization, sql-server-2012

I'm installing the 180 day trial of SQL Server 2012 on a virtual machine with the intent of buying a license for it later on. From past experiences with installing SQL Server I would always make specific user accounts for the SQL Server to use. Looking at the installer now, its pre-populating the accounts with specific ones of its own:

- SQL Server Agent - **NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT**
- SQL Server Database Engine - **NT Service\MSSQLSERVER**
- SQL Server Analysis Services - **NT Service\MSSQLServerOLAPService**
- SQL Server Reporting Services - **NT Service\ReportServer**
- SQL Server Integration Services 11.0 - **NT Service\MsDtsServer110**
- SQL Server Distributed Replay Client - **NT Service\SQL Server Distributed Replay Client**
- SQL Server Distributed Replay Controller - **NT Service\SQL Server Distributed Replay Controller**
- SQL Full-text Filter Daemon Launcher - **NT Service\MSSQLFDLauncher**
- SQL Server Browser - **NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE**

In the past (SQL Server 2008 R2) the Agent, Engine, Analysis Services and Reporting Services would be blank and I'd specify the accounts I made. Before I got to this screen on the installation I had already made new user accounts, as domain accounts, but I see that the installer is pre-populating with local accounts.

In the end, should I let the installer make the accounts it wants to make or should I replace them with the accounts I've made?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are in an AD environment, I would recommend using AD accounts for SQL Services. When you do things like backup, if you are running under builtin accounts permissions can become a pain (same with things like log shipping).

In other words, I have made the mistake of using the built-in accounts, and learned my lesson :-)

Comment: Well, sounds good enough for me, thanks for the input!